# Trying to pass a key to argument on custom function to display all values from the data

Tags: jquery, function, loops, each

When I call the function with the argument, it doesn't show anything.

I tried below and it works but when I added it inside the function it stopped working.

WORKING

```
var data = [

  {"blue": ['Volvo','Saab','Mercedes']},
  {"wheel": ['Saab','Mercedes','BMW']},
  {"fast": ['Saab','BMW','Ford']}

];

$.each(data, function(i) {
  var plans = data[i].blue;
    $.each(plans, function(b,qf) {
      console.log(qf);
    });
});
```

NOT WORKING

```
var data = [

  {"blue": ['Volvo','Saab','Mercedes']},
  {"wheel": ['Saab','Mercedes','BMW']},
  {"fast": ['Saab','BMW','Ford']}

];

function aData(selected) {
  $.each(data, function(i) {
    var plans = data[i].selected;
      $.each(plans, function(b,qf) {
        console.log(qf);
      });
  });
}

aData(blue);
```

I expect it to show all values for the key: blue. But nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

1) The `.selected` is messing you up.  Use `[selected]`.

2) Make sure you're using a string for your input on the last line.  It breaks the example, but I am guessing you're calling this from elsewhere in your actual application.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = [

      {"blue": ['Volvo','Saab','Mercedes']},
      {"wheel": ['Saab','Mercedes','BMW']},
      {"fast": ['Saab','BMW','Ford']}

    ];

    function aData(selected) {
      $.each(data, function(i) {
        var plans = data[i][selected];
        if (plans) {
          $.each(plans, function(b,qf) {
            console.log(qf);
          });
          }
      });
    }

    aData('blue');
```